# Python adding more than one thing to a single variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import numpy as py
name=''
myname=str('Your name, your name')
while True:
    print("What is your name?")
    name=input('')
    if name== myname:
        print("Please enter a valid name")
    elif name != myname:
        print("Thank you for providing a name")



        break
print('Thank you')
```

Hello everyone. I'm having an issue and would greatly appreciate some help in. I'm a beginner and was wondering how can I add more conditions or names to a variable. If you can see from line 3, I am attempting to add more than one name whereby the user must re-enter a name if they put write it in the input. If the user writes a variation of your name or Your name or anything else I don't see fit as a name, how could I put it all in one variable? Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Python has a few data types worth exploring. Lists, dicts, sets ,tuples,etc. A list is more like an array in c,c++.  And this is how you can add more than one item to a list. So declare your variable as follows:

```
name=list[]
...
.... 
name.append(input(""))
```

Also give list comprehension a read. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for providing a suggestion. I tried your suggestion, but it says that I'm placing more than one argument.

Answer (score -1):

you would use a list

```
mynames=[
    'Your name',
    'your name',
    'Another name'
]
```

then check

```
if name in mynames:
    print("Please enter a valid name")
else:
    print("Thank you for providing a name")
    break
```

so your full code would be

```
import numpy as py
name=''
mynames=[
    'Your name',
    'your name',
    'Another name'
]

while True:
    print("What is your name?")
    name=input('')
    if name in mynames:
        print("Please enter a valid name")
    else:
        print("Thank you for providing a name")
        break

print('Thank you')
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. Unfortunately, when I did that previously, it did not execute as intended and instead remained on the if statement and shortly after, broke out of its loop without going back (despite it being a name I did not see fit for the input)

Comment: I just copy pasted my full code and actually ran it, works fine for me. If you type one of the names in the list it says "Please enter a valid name" otherwise if it isn't in the list it says "Thank you for providing a name" and then "Thank you"